# Entity Framework 4 many to many relationship issue

Tags: entity-framework

Considering this database:
[image]

This is what EF generates:
[image]

I think that HeroesItem class, is useless, and there should be a navigation property Items on Hero class and a navigation property Heroes on Item class.

I saw this can be done easily with code first, but how to get it done using database first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done only if your `HeroesItems` table does not contain `Id` column and instead uses `IdHero` and `IdItem` as composite primary key. Once you add any additional column to junction table you must map it as entity to have control over that column.